# Query do work if I filter out data that is NOT in my dataset - but not otherwise

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a problem I have never been close to experience before. I start with giving you the code.

```
WITH cte_exclude AS ( --List of "bad data quarters" for an insurance
SELECT DISTINCT 
    AR.InsuranceNumber
    ,AR.AccountNumber
    ,CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(AR.ValueDate)) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(QUARTER, AR.ValueDate)), 2) AS [QuarterNumber]
FROM
    tableAccountReturns AR
WHERE
    AccountReturn >=1
    or AccountReturn <=-1)

,cte_clean AS ( --Clear all data corresponding to quarters in the exclude cte
SELECT
    AR.*
    ,X.QuarterNumber
FROM
    tableAccountReturns AR
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
            (CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(AR.ValueDate)) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(QUARTER, AR.ValueDate)), 2)) AS [QuarterNumber]
    ) X
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            cte_exclude EX
        WHERE
            EX.InsuranceNumber = AR.InsuranceNumber
            AND EX.QuarterNumber = X.QuarterNumber
    ))

SELECT 
InsuranceNumber
,AccountNumber
,QuarterNumber
,(
    exp(SUM(log(CASE
        WHEN (1+AccountReturn) < 0 THEN --Should not happen since we are excluding those data points
            (1+AccountReturn)*(-1)
        ELSE
            (1+AccountReturn)
        END)
        ))
    ) * (
    CASE (SUM(CASE WHEN (1+AccountReturn) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) % 2)
        WHEN 1 THEN -1
        WHEN 0 THEN 1
    END
    ) - 1 AS [PortfolioReturnQuarter]
FROM
cte_clean C
WHERE
AccountReturn <> -1
GROUP BY
InsuranceNumber, AccountNumber, QuarterNumber
```

This code works when I have `WHERE AccountReturn <> -1` but not otherwise. If I check the cte_clean it does not contain any data that is `<= -1`. I.e. the filtering is working as intended.

The error message I receive when trying to execute the query without the WHERE clause is:

> Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

What can cause this?

Comment: can you please provide a full [mre] eventually as dbfiddle

Comment: `Log`  will throw this error if you are passing an argument of 0 or a negative number. If AccountReturn = -1, (1+AccountReturn)*(-1) will return 0.

Comment: @Andrew Yes exactly, I know that. But I have double checked and no data point is -1 in the data set. So I'm excluding nothing with that where clause.